# How to execute a TShortcut programmatically?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-xe2

```
procedure ExecuteAShortCut(AShortCut: System.Classes.TShortCut);
begin
  // This will have the same effect as when the user presses this shortcut on the keyboard:
  DoExecuteThisShortCut(AShortCut);
end;
```

How could `DoExecuteThisShortCut` be implemented?

Comment: E.g. [`ShortCutToKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCutToKey) can give you virtual key with shift state and [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) simulate a keystroke.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. How can I mark this question as solved?

Comment: What if your app does not have input focus?

Comment: In the specific case where I use this the application does have input focus.

Comment: Can check with GetFocus <> 0

Comment: Contrary the name `IsShortCut` actually executes associated menu/action/etc if any.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Could you please clarify? How can the associated menu/action be executed?

Comment: @user It's a little odd that you want to do this. Why don't you just call a method directly?

Comment: @user1580348, click dispatched for menu item, onexecute - for action, check out `TCutsomForm.IsShortCut`, specifically local `DispatchShortCut`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's too complicated to explain.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Sorry, I don't understand. Could you please provide an example for: "dispatched for menu item"?

Comment: I doubt that very much

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, I need this for a situation where ShortCuts entered by the user on the keyboard cannot trigger the associated menu items. So if I am able to automatically trigger the click of the menu-item associated with the shortcut the problem would be solved.

Comment: You are right. It's too complicated to explain!! ;-) One cannot help feeling that you have not got to the bottom of your problem.

Comment: IsShortCut is no good if you ask me. You have to construct a key message and then press ctrl and/or shift as necessary.

Comment: You have to check the source and figure out if it suits you needs. @SertacAkyuz, agree with you, however I do not see other way to "plug" into existing keyboard dispatching code.